# modificar elementos de un Block view Drupal 8

Tags: php, twig, drupal, cms

Buenas tardes,

he creado un `block view` con su respectivo template , lo pongo a continuación:

```
    {%
      set classes = [
'block',
'block-' ~ configuration.provider|clean_class,
'block-' ~ plugin_id|clean_class,
     ]
     %}
 <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
 {{ title_prefix }}
 {% if label %}
  <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
 {% endif %}
{{ title_suffix }}
{% block content %}
<div{{ content_attributes.addClass('content') }}>
  {{ content }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Todo funciona bien, se muestra correctamente con los campos que he puesto en su `content type` pero quiero modificarlos , nose que variable en twig tendria que usar o que hacer para recoger los valores de los campos.

La duda es que no sé cómo modificar a mi antojo los elementos del `block` dentro de la plantilla.

Quiero recoger los valores de los campos y usarlos a mi antojo.

Answer (score 0):

Llego un poco tarde pero lo que puedes hacer es llamar a los `fields` que necesites desde la variable `content` por ejemplo `{{ content.body }} {{ content.field_EL_NOMBRE_DE_TU_FIELD }}`.

En la documentación de Drupal puedes encontrar filters y functions que pueden ser de utilidad [Twig in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig)